# How to replace the content in every line of text file?

Tags: notepad++

I am having a bunch of lines with following format in Notepad++ file.

Current Format is as follows:

```
Line 1:     2017-05-26 02:26:40,362 Executing SQL query [ Select * from T1 ]
Line 2:     2017-05-26 02:26:40,362 Executing SQL query [ Select * from T2 ] 
Line 3:     2017-05-26 02:26:40,362 Executing SQL query [ Select * from T3 ] 
Line 4:     2017-05-26 02:26:40,362 Executing SQL query [ Select * from T1 ]
```

Expected result on each line is as follows after replace:

```
Select * from T1 
Select * from T2 
Select * from T3 
Select * from T1
```

I also need the expected result in the following format as well:

```
2017-05-26 02:26:40,362     Select * from T1 
2017-05-26 02:26:41,367     Select * from T2 
2017-05-26 02:26:45,762     Select * from T3
```

How to achieve it in Notepad++?

Comment: This would be ***so*** much easier in [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace matches of regexp `^.*\[ | \].*$` with an empty string in the Replace window (`Ctrl+H`). Just make sure that you have Search mode set to `Regular expression`.

Comment: It is working. Many thanks for the exact answer provided :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

txt = '''
Line 1:     2017-05-26 02:26:40,362 Executing SQL query [ Select * from T1 ]
Line 2:     2017-05-26 02:26:40,362 Executing SQL query [ Select * from T2 ]
Line 3:     2017-05-26 02:26:40,362 Executing SQL query [ Select * from T3 ]
Line 4:     2017-05-26 02:26:40,362 Executing SQL query [ Select * from T1 ]
'''

txt_new = [re.findall(r'(Select \* from T[0-9]+)', i)[0] for i in txt.split('\n') if i]
print(txt_new)
```